# Python Pandas: sort a dataframe by multiple columns but different sorting order

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I have a question about sorting a dataframe in Pandas.
For example I have a dataframe 'df_cars' with the columns 'Year','Model','Mileage','Price'.
And I want to display the dataframe ordered by 'Year' (desc) and 'Mileage' (asc).
I know how to sort by multiple colulmns but the same order (asc/or desc):

```
print(df_cars.sort_values(by=['Year','Price'], inplace = False, ascending = True)
```

The values for 'Year' and 'Price' will be both ordered in ascending way.
But if I have several values for the same year, and want to see the years in ascending order and  the prices in descending order.
What should I do?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Specify a [list of bool](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) that matches the list of `by` for the `ascending` parameter.

Comment: use a list `ascending = [True, False]`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
print(df_cars.sort_values(by=['Year','Price'], inplace = False, ascending = (0,1))
```

Answer (score 0):

I will try.
By myself I did:

```
print(df_cars.sort_values(by=['Year','Price'],
                          inplace = False, 
                          ascending = (False,True))
```

I suppose it is the same as your suggestion.
I tried both versions and got the same output.

Thank you.